# BASH Can't add to $PATH

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to add new variable to $PATH but everytime i try, it't wont show after in echo $PATH.

```
if echo "$PATH" | grep -q "$sciezka" ; then
        echo "Sciezka $sciezka is in the PATH"
        else
        export PATH=$PATH:$sciezka
        fi
```

I've tried `source ~/.bashrc` but it didn't worked

When I use:

```
echo "$PATH:$sciezka"
```

to test, it works fine, but after test it won't stay in $PATH.

Whole Code(Updated with https://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
#!/bin/bash
pliczek=0
function jakasnazwa {
        plik=$1
        if [ -z "$plik" ]
        then
         echo "Podaj ścieżke pliku"
         read plik
         pliczek="$plik"
         touch $pliczek
        else
         pliczek="$plik"
         touch $pliczek
        fi

        if [ -f "zad1.sh" ]
        then
        echo "Plik zad1.sh istnieje"
        else
        echo "Plik zad1.sh nie istnieje"
        fi

        sciezka=$(pwd)

sciezka="$(pwd)"


        if echo "$PATH" | grep -q "$sciezka" ; then
        echo "Scieżka $sciezka znajduje się w PATH"
        else
         zmienna="$PATH:$sciezka"
        export PATH="$zmienna"
        fi

        if [[ -d 'katalog' ]]
        then
        rm -r 'katalog'
        mkdir 'katalog'
        else
        mkdir 'katalog'
        fi
        dir >> $pliczek
        mv $pliczek './katalog/'
}

jakasnazwa "$1"
```

Comment: Do `export PATH="$PATH:$sciezka"` just in case there are spaces in any path.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Do you want to use the added path afterwards outside your script in variable $PATH or only in the script?

Comment: @Cyrus I want to use it only in script.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've tried this way and also `sciezka=$(pwd) sciezka=$(echo $sciezka | tr -d '[:space:]')`

Comment: @kotinerus Please put a [mre] in your question so that we can run the script and observe the same issue. Why would you remove the spaces from the paths btw? That would render them unusable.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've added it. I've tried `export PATH=$PATH:pwd` instead of $sciezka, but it didn't worked as well.

Comment: No, you should do `sciezka="$(pwd)"` and `export PATH="$PATH:$sciezka"` (or just `export PATH="$PATH:$PWD"`) - the double quotes are always important in [tag:bash]. Put your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix all problems it reports

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've placed it in shellcheck.net(1 minor change) and tried `export PATH="$PATH:$sciezka"` just like your other sugestions and nothing works.

Comment: Put the updated code that passes through shellcheck.net without complaints in the question.

Comment: Now, how exactly do you run this script, and then determine that `PATH` doesn't look like the way you expect it to?

Comment: You should never have interactive IO in your bashrc script - that's what .profile/.bash_profile is for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to modify the PATH value **for usage within the script performing the test**, then the logic you defined above applies correctly for any subsequent logic within that script itself.

If you are trying to modify the PATH value **for usage for ANY terminal/shell that you open from your GUI/scripts** (*without having to insert that above logic every time in those scripts/sessions*), you need to incorporate that logic within the **.bashrc_local** script.  That script's purpose is to capture any custom environment logic outside the **.bashrc** which could get clobbered by OS updates.

Once proviso, you need to ensure that your match pattern does not allow for possible substring match, thereby being an invalid match.  To that end, your

```
grep -q "$sciezka"
```

should actually be of the form

```
grep -E -q "^${sciezka};|;${sciezka};|;${sciezka}$"
```

Comment: Worth noting the simple rule **"A child can never modify the environment of its parent"** which is what you explain paragraph 2. Giving a simple rule can help cement the concept.